# External links are not working in phonegap apk

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, inappbrowser

External links are not working in phonegap apk .I started developing my application in phonegap and viewed through phonegap desktop app and it worked fine,then I started to generate apk in phonegap build then I found that external links are not working properly and so my font style(font family) also differs.I tried to rectify it through window open commands but window open commands are also not working .

```
$(".footer ").on('click','#facebook',function(){

         window.open("https://facebook.com/");
    });
    $("#twitter").click(function(){
               window.open("https://twitter.com/");
    });
    $("#instagram").click(function(){
               window.open("https://www.instagram.com/");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` and change code to:

```
$(".footer ").on('click','#facebook',function(){
     window.open("https://facebook.com/", "_system", "");
});
$("#twitter").click(function(){
           window.open("https://twitter.com/", "_system", "");
});
$("#instagram").click(function(){
           window.open("https://www.instagram.com/", "_system", "");
});
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/